# Using VMWare Fusion to access GPUs

Tags: gpu, vmware, vmware-fusion

I am running the VM Fusion 8 Pro with Ubuntu 14.04 on a MacPro. The MacPro comes with dual AMD FirePro D500 GPUs. I installed the AMD APP SDK within Ubuntu, but it is only seeing the CPU as a device, and not the GPUs. Can someone please guide me so that I can run OpenCL kernels on the GPU(s).

Googling has revealed things like GPU passthrough, but there isn't enough detail on how to exactly access a GPU from within VMWare Fusion.

Sincerely,

Vishal

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked it was necessary to have motherboard support to allow the virtual machines to access the GPUs.